# Toggle table row with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row, toggle

I have a table where I click on a parent row which shows/hides child row with certain CSS class.
The thing is that .toggle() is triggered with a click on a parent row and I would like to be triggered only by clicking on span with a class btn which is inside parent row.

This is HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent" id="2479">
      <td><span class="btn">text</span></td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-2479">
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent')
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle('slow');
        });
    $('tr[class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/esedic/Hjhb8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the selector to

`$('tr.parent td span.btn').click(function(){...});`

this will get you any `span` with the class `button` in a `td` that is in a `tr` with the class `parent`

**UPDATE**

If the table is created dynamically you can use the `on()` function instead of a click, if i'm understanding you right.

I see what you mean, even though your question doesnt reflect it.
I updated the fiddle for you.

This is the jquery that you want:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent td')
        .on("click","span.btn", function(){
            var idOfParent = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
            $('tr.child-'+idOfParent).toggle('slow');
        });
});
```

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjhb8/7/)

Comment: The thing is that parent an child rows are created dynamically.
Parent row ID (in this case 2479) is basis for child row class (child-2479).
So I have to read this numerical value from parent row ID and trigger toggle only on child rows with class that contains that ID.

Comment: It works great!
I've just added this line:

$('tr[class^=child-]').hide().children('td');

Here is the final example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esedic/8XxkL/)

Comment: You could hide that with CSS instead and make your JS less cluttered, just a tip! :)

Comment: This answer will not work for dynamically added table rows because the eventhandler is being attached to existing `span.btn` elements.

Comment: Updated the answer so that it reflects the api correctly and attaches current and future elements. :) Nice catch @Bruno! :)

Comment: I've updated my code with your suggestions (JS eventhandler, hide child row with CSS).
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("tr.parent > td").on( "click", "span.btn", function() {

    var childId = $(this).parents("tr").prop("id");
    $("tr.child-" + childId).toggle("slow");
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/MBzE6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
 $("body").on("click", "tr span.btn", function(event){
     $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle('slow');
 });
```